# User manager CreateAsync running very slow - Identity 2

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6, asp.net-identity-2

I'm running this query to import uses from an old MySQL database to a new SQL database using entity framework and Microsoft's Identity 2 and on the local server Visual Studio Community edition runs alongside SQL Server 10.0.5

**User manager declaration**

```
private ApplicationUserManager _userManager;
public ApplicationUserManager UserManager
{
    get
    {
        if (_userManager == null)
        {
            this._userManager = HttpContext.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
            this._userManager.PasswordValidator = new CustomPasswordValidator();
        }
        return _userManager;
    }
    private set
    {
        _userManager = value;
    }
}
```

**Controller methods** - *the sql and MySQL unit of work are in the controller construct, only 1 context per db is made for this entire process*

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
{
    await ImportUsers();

    return View();
}

private async Task<bool> ImportUsers()
{
    DateTime timeNow = DateTime.Now;

    // Returns a full list of old users in about a millisecond
    List<default_users> users = 
        this.mySQLUnitOfWork
        .MySQLRepo
        .GetUsers()
        .ToList(); 

    foreach (var user in users)
    {                  
        if (user.username != null && user.email != null &&
            user.username != "" && user.email != "" &&
            UserManager.FindByEmail(user.email) == null)
        {
            default_profiles profile = 
                this.mySQLUnitOfWork
                    .MySQLRepo
                    .GetProfiles()
                    .Where(x => 
                        x.id == user.id
                    ).FirstOrDefault();

            if (profile != null)
            {          
                var newUser = new ApplicationUser { 
                    UserName = user.username.ToLower(), 
                    Email = user.email.ToLower(), 
                    CreatedAt = timeNow, 
                    UpdatedAt = timeNow 
                };

                newUser.Profile = new UserProfile { 
                    CreatedAt = timeNow, 
                    UpdatedAt = timeNow, 
                    FirstName = profile.first_name, 
                    LastName = profile.last_name, 
                    User = newUser 
                };

                // Takes ages to complete
                var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(
                    newUser, 
                    Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N")
                );

                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                    UserManager.AddToRole(newUser.Id, RoleChoices.MEMBER);             
                    var dbUser = this.sqlUnitOfWork.UserRepository.GetByID(newUser.Id);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

**Problem:**

***This operation takes at least 45 minutes for 2000 user records***. It seems that the CreateAsync and AddToRole methods take absolutely ages to run. Any reasons why this might be?

**Note:**

I have been debugging this to death... The slowest part is waiting for the CreateAsync method to complete... It's really quite odd? It takes atleast 1 second to create a user.

Comment: Profile the code. Are there profilers for async code? If not pause the debugger 10 times and see what's on the stack most often.

Comment: I'll take a look at the profiling, thanks for the tip.

Comment: @Jimmyt1988 im running into same issue currently. Did you find any fix for this issue?

Comment: @Jimmyt1988 Did you find a solution? I'm running into the same problem here.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are not destroying your Context/Repository, if you keep your repository alive for entire application scope, it will grow in size. It is bad practice, usually repository should only live along with request life cycle, it should be created when new request starts and it will be disposed when request finishes.

Comment: This all happens within 1 controller... Thus it's 1 request. The context is created within the construct of my controller inside unit of work, and then removed at the end of the controller's life, thus once the controller method finishes it's process, my memory is returned back to normal. Are you supposing I delete the context and remake it every loop of creating each user? It doesn't seem right.

Comment: where and how this  ApplicationUserManager received from HttpContext.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager> is destroyed?